# yaws crashes with httpc:request for URL served by docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, erlang, yaws, adminer

I use `yaws` and `adminer` in my docker stack. Formerly, I used to route `https://mydomain.tld/adm?foo=bar` with `nginx` to the proper container via

```
    location /adm/ {
        proxy_pass         http://adm:8080;
    }
```

How to do that in `yaws`?

The idea is to get the result from the container `adm` directly. Entering the `yaws` container and issuing `curl -v 'http://adm:8080'` works as expected.

My Erlang code is straightforward, but I get an error I cannot make sense of. I start with parsing the URL for `adm` and if true translate the URL from `https://mydomain.tld/adm?foo=bar` to `http://adm:8080?foo=bar` and then call `out_adm`

```
out_adm(Url, A) ->
    inets:start(),
    Http_result = httpc:request(Url),
    case Http_result of
        {ok, {{_Version, 200, _ReasonPhrase}, _Headers, Html}} ->               
?trace('out_check_adm(A)======PASS_THROUGH HTML====> Url', [Url]),  
                    Html; 
        _ -> 
            not_200 
    end.
```

With the help of trace I know that `Http_result` is ok with `Status` 200.

```
Mod:myurl line:863 'out_adm(A)=====PASS_THROUGH HTML====> Url' ["http://adm:8080"]
=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Oct-2021::17:55:28.784448 ===
yaws code at appmod:0 crashed or ret bad val:60
Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/adm"},{1,1}}
```

I'm left with no clue. To me all is clear and easy, hence the error comes as a surprise. What is the problem? How can I understand the error message? Is something wrong with `Html`? If so, what?

Looking at the definition in https://github.com/erlyaws/yaws/blob/master/src/yaws_server.erl did not help me:

```
handle_out_reply(Reply, LineNo, YawsFile, _UT, ARG) ->
    L =  ?F("yaws code at ~s:~p crashed or "
            "ret bad val:~p ~nReq: ~p",
            [YawsFile, LineNo, Reply, ARG#arg.req]),
    handle_crash(ARG, L).
```

How can I debug this? Is this a problem of `docker` or `yaws`?

Comment: Found my mistake while reading https://www.infoq.com/articles/vinoski-erlang-rest/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530042/html-is-not-applying-the-css-when-viewed-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Found my error:

Instead of a simple `Html;` in my `out_adm` function it has to be `{html, Html};`

But now I face another problem: See [HTML is not applying the CSS when viewed in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530042/html-is-not-applying-the-css-when-viewed-in-browser)