# HTML is not applying the CSS when viewed in browser

Tags: css, docker, browser, yaws, adminer

I use adminer in a docker container.

For testing services, I use the URL `mydomain.tld`. To address this container directly, I could expose a port and map, for example, port `8081` to the adminer port `8080`.

Addressing this container directly via `http://mydomain.tld:8081` works without problem, everything is as it should and the Login dialog looks like that:

[image: normal appearance of Login dialog]

However, this approach exposes user and password, so it should not be used.

Using the same docker container via https, however, I get a faulty page. In this case the container is called via the address `https://mydomain.tld/adm` which is forwarded by the web server addressing `mydomain.tld` at port 443 to the adminer container to serve the request. The approach is straightforward. The result is identical to the former. Why does this not work?

I used `nginx` as a proxy and connecting to the adminer container was fine. Now I use `yaws` and pass through the call to the adminer container.

[image: faulty rendering of Login dialog]

Obviously the js and css files are not applied by the browser, be it Opera, Chrome, UR, Vivaldi, Edge or Firefox, although the source code is correct and fine. No browser shows errors in the console except Firefox (error messages translated by Bing, emphasis by me), but these errors are obviously attributed erroneously:

> Stylesheet https://mydomain.tld/adm?file=default.css&version=4.8.1 was not loaded because its MIME type, **text/html**, is not **text/css**.

> The script of https://mydomain.tld/adm?file=functions.js&version=4.8.1 was loaded even though its MIME type (**text/html**) is not a MIME type valid for **JavaScript**.

These error messages are not correct, as can be seen in the source code: The MIME type definitely is `text/css`, rel is `stylesheet` and script should be Javascript anyway.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="?file=default.css&amp;version=4.8.1">
<script src='?file=functions.js&amp;version=4.8.1' nonce="ZDA0ODE4Y2ZhZWY1NzkyZTUxNzg3MGZlNTdlNTcxM2M="></script>
```

Why does Firefox interpret them as `text/html` (as do probably the other browsers, too)?

Granted, the respective URLs using `GET` variables do not *look* like standard files, but they should work nevertheless and they actually do work either way as can be shown by several methods:

1. As mentioned, the same source code works well when the container is called via `html` and port 8081.
2. A click on these links in the HTML source of the `https` version loads the files without problem in any browser, as it should.
3. Likewise the developer tools network analysis shows HTTP code 200 for all of them, even in Firefox.

This proves in my eyes that the code received by the browser is OK, no problem here. Either way the source code is identical, except for the path.

I even manipulated the output of the adminer container to provide for the full path, but, as was to be expected, this didn't change a thing, as also proven by the following scenario:

Use the source code of either output in a local file. Here the references cannot be augmented by the browser, so we have to add the full path manually. By switching the path `FULL_PATH` between the `http` and `https` version I can reproduce the behavior from a local file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FULL_PATH?file=default.css&amp;version=4.8.1"> 
<!-- http://mydomain.tld:8081/ works; https://mydomain.tld/adm/ works per click, but not in browser-->
```

This file is not even https, as it is called from a local file, only one link is.

Why don't the browsers open these files in the `https` case as would be natural despite developer tools telling all is OK? What is the problem here? Is there a hidden switch preventing to render these files with https?

How can I debug this more intelligently in order to find the reason and a remedy? I ran out of ideas by now.

See also [yaws crashes with httpc:request for URL served by docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529197/yaws-crashes-with-httpcrequest-for-url-served-by-docker-container/69529938#69529938) for how the html content is produced.

Comment: I found something peculiar. Using curl I see that the address is called only once. The reason is that curl does not care for css, js and the like. Using a browser, additional calls are initiated, as is to be expected, like http://adm:8080/?file=default.css&version=4.8.1. But there is one call which is not to be expected: "http://adm:8080/?script=version. No idea where this does come from. Maybe this is causing the error. I'll try to weed this out and see what I get.

Comment: Sorry, this workaround did not work out either.

Comment: The workaround with port 8081 is no that bad if I restrict port 8081 to my own IP. So I can live happily with that, but I am still curious to solve this enigma.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Firefox interpret them as text/html (as do probably the other browsers, too)?

If you look in the "Network" tab of the developer tools, I'm pretty sure that you're going to see that these files are served with a `Content-type: text/html` HTTP response header, so the browser treats them as HTML instead of CSS and Javascript.

Looking at the Yaws documentation, it seems like your `out_adm` function needs to return <s>`{content, "text/css", Content}` or `{content, "text/javascript", Content}`</s> `[{header, {content_type, "text/javascript"}}, {html, Html}]` (as per [Steve Vinoski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530042/html-is-not-applying-the-css-when-viewed-in-browser/69559234?noredirect=1#comment123007152_69559234)) instead of `{http, Content}` in order to respond with the correct header.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds very reasonable. Your hypothesis is correct. Your remedy does not work, however: appmod:0 crashed or ret bad val:{html,"text/javascript", .... I conclude the syntax is wrong. Where did you find information about sending css/js in Yaws? I googled for an hour and did not find a hint of how to add this type of header information. I tried e.g. calling yaws_api:mime_type(global, ".css"), before {html, Html}; to no avail.

Comment: I got this from http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws_api . Halfway down under "Return values from out/1" it mentions both `{html, DeepList}` and `{content, MimeType, Content}`, so I thought that would work...

Comment: Assuming you're using Yaws 2.0.9, our best bet for detailed documentation is the [2.0.9 yaws.pdf file](https://github.com/erlyaws/yaws/releases/download/yaws-2.0.9/yaws.pdf). There, it explains that "[The `{content, ...}]` return value is only allowed in a YAWS file which has only one <erl> </erl> part and no html parts at all." If you're using an appmod, you want to return a `{header, {content_type, "text/css"}}` header specifier as part of your response as documented on page 36 of the pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you. Sorry, somehow I didn't get notice, so I am late. I changed my code to {header, {content_type, "text/javascript"}}, {html, Html}; This isn't it, though. No error, but  Warning: a term is constructed, but never used. What am I doing wrong? Also, Firefox developer tools not only deliver 200 html, but a click on e.g. the css file reveals Request Headers (504 B) with Accept text/css,*/*;q=0.1 so why is this qualified as html nevertheless?

Comment: Like I said, you want the header specifier as part of your response; you're getting the warning because the header is not in the response. Try returning `[{header, {content_type, "text/javascript"}}, {html, Html}]` instead.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, I'd never find out myself. The form now looks as it should, the files are recognized as css and script, but the form does not work, keeps reappearing instead. Looking at trace data, I get 403 (auth) at first try, then 200, so this looks ok, i.e. the credentials are accepted, i.e. POST data transferred, correct? But why can't I log in then? I reckoned I need to check POST data (got this: auth[driver]=server&auth[server]=master&auth[username]=...) and must pass it to httpc:request to the adm container. Correct? But why is POST data working first, then not?

Comment: I see that `A#arg.clidata` is `undefined` when sending the login dialog. That should be the reason why it returns. Why is that so? I should see my credentials. I copied form stackoverflow `Parsed = yaws_api:parse_query( A#arg{ querydata = A#arg.clidata } ),`, the result is `[[]]`. Clueless again.

Comment: I am sorry, I just noticed I looked at a wrong position -- of course css and the like do not give POST data. I do see login data in both positions, so I can investigate further.

Comment: Yaws knows the POST data: How to pass this on to adminer as POST? Is this possible? GET would be easy. I guess revproxy could be a solution if I had a certificate for adm.mydomain.tld (which would be doable). In fact I have a subdomain mail which I don't use except for Thunderbird, so I could try this one. If I revproxy that to http://adm I get `Exception: undef Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/"},{1,1}} Stack: [{out404,out404,...`

Comment: I found my mistake: adm listens on port 8080, so `revproxy = / http://adm:8080` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the workaround was superfluous and the solution was easy: use Yaws with `revproxy = / http://adm:8080` in `yaws.conf` using a new server instruction `abc.mydomain.tld`.

Nevertheless, there was a lot to learn. Thank you both for your efforts.